# Saving formatted date strings to the database in Rails3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, date

I'm using a JQuery UI DatePicker to choose dates on one of the forms in the app I'm writing. Thus, my form input is a generic text field and I'm accepting a free form date string. According to [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars), saving these strings to the database (I'm using MySQL) should "just work." I'm finding that not to be the case though. When I save my form, it's interpreting the date in the form: dd/mm/yyyy, when I'm entering mm/dd/yyyy. Is there a way to tell rails that I'm going to be entering dates in the mm/dd/yyyy format, or do I need to monkey around with the data in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine writer method in model

```
def my_date=(value)
  write_attribute :my_date, Time.strptime(value, "%m/%d/%Y")
end
```